# ¿Se puede empaquetar una aplicacion web en lenguaje java, hecha con Openxava, dentro de una aplicacion .jar manteniendo la interfaz gráfica?

Tags: java, web, jar, openxava

Lo que sucede es que he desarrollado una aplicación web, en java, con OpenXava, pero quisiera empaquetada en un jar, manteniendo la conexión con la base de datos, sería posible?